# Message Aggregation using SQS and SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, amazon-sqs

I have a use case/situation wherein, SQS(standard) will be flooded with messages (north of 500k+), a microservice (spring boot based) listens to these events, consumes it, and makes a rest API call (batch-based) to 3rd party SaaS system (have attached a high-level diagram for the same)
The limitation here is that the spring boot consumer can receive a max of 10 messages from the SQS, transform the payload, and makes the rest API call with these 10 messages(records).

Is there a way to aggregate these messages to say 100 messages, before making the rest API call (assuming that the target SaaS System accepts 100 records of data)? Would spring batch helps in this case?

Should I have to look at a different stack for this kind of need? Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is actually the chunk-oriented processing model of Spring Batch: items could be read from the queue, accumulated in chunks of 100 items (that is the configurable chunk-size) and posted to your REST API in bulk mode.

Spring Batch handles the chunking of items (and much more) for you. So yes, even though I'm biased, I believe Spring Batch is a very good option for your use case.

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Ben Hassine  did a rudimentary spike to check for message aggregation read from SQS using spring batch (chunk processing model), it is working. here is the code which I uploaded it to [github](https://github.com/vasupatnaik/sqs-aggregator-spike)

Comment: @user9142486 Good to hear it is working for you. Thank you for sharing the code!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try Spring Aggregator(Spring Integration).

> The Aggregator combines a group of related messages, by correlating
> and storing them until the group is deemed to be complete. At that
> point, the aggregator creates a single message by processing the whole
> group and sends the aggregated message as output.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/aggregator.html

And please refer to this GitHub repo for spring integration with AWS services
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/tree/main/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/aws

I'm assuming you are having multiple instances of your application and can scale up easily if required (since you have 500k+ messages). But still, your application is prone to data loss. So building a reliable system is always challenging. Since you are already on the cloud and maybe you should think about utilizing different cloud services.

I think for your case, you should have a look at the AWS Kinesis dataStream and Kinesis data fire hose.
You can refer this,
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/stream-data-to-an-http-endpoint-with-amazon-kinesis-data-firehose/